# writing ouput from anova.rma(metafor) to a csv or dataframe

Tags: r, metafor

I have done multiple anova.rma functions from the metafor package to compare 2 vs. 3 level models in a meta-analysis, and the output in the console is a nice table. I would like to write this to a csv so that I can store these results, however the object that is saved in the environment is a list and I am having trouble actually writing this output in a nice format. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Update: I added an example data and script so that maybe others can reproduce the problem I have been having easier
https://github.com/jmmakoshark/anova.rma/blob/main/anova_rma_ex.csv
https://github.com/jmmakoshark/anova.rma/blob/main/anova_rma_ex.r

[output from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbumC.png)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). Have you tried `write.table()` with the results from `summary()`?

Comment: Hi, sorry if there is not enough info I'm new to this. I've been working out of an online textbook and think that has the best example to illustrate the function: https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/multilevel-ma.html#model-fitting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `as.data.frame()` method for `anova.rma` objects. So, just do `as.data.frame(anova(...))` and then you get a plain data frame that you can write to a csv file.

Comment: When I try that I get this error message, and I keep getting stuck here where I can't coerce > as.data.frame(anova(est_MILK2,est_MILK3))
Error in as.data.frame.default(anova(est_MILK2, est_MILK3)) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"anova.rma"’ to a data.frame

Comment: Do you have the most recent version (3.8-1) of metafor installed? https://cran.r-project.org/package=metafor

Comment: I did not. I had 3.4 and just updated it, and now everything works. Thanks so much for the help!